# angularjs execute function for dropdown menu item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I follow the example here http://plnkr.co/edit/f3cc22cDkIh88svQtrxB?p=preview for dropdown menu, but the data is inside the js file as object.

```
  $scope.items = [
    "Edit",
    "Delete"
  ];
```

how can I run a function if edit is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<li ng-repeat="choice in items">
  <a ng-click="doSomething(choice)">{{choice}}</a>
</li>


$scope.doSomething = function(choice) {
    switch(choice) {

    }
};
```

Comment: this way work. you can check on this code
http://plnkr.co/edit/lljbfGNXfFX9QdfghqGg?p=preview

Comment: use switch - you can have more choice you want easily

Answer (score 0):

You can use this little trick to conditionally execute stuff in directives that take expressions, such as `ng-click`.

```
<a ng-click="choice == 'Edit' && doSomethingOnEdit(choice)">{{choice}}</a>
```

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/sd5deepCKLTgx6K6la8a?p=preview)

Or just filter it out inside your function, if the condition is complex.

```
<a ng-click="doSomethingOnEdit(choice)">{{choice}}</a>
```

(in your controller)

```
$scope.doSomethingOnEdit = function(value) {
     if (value != 'Edit') return;
     // otherwise, do whatever
};
```

Comment: what if I have more than 2 choice? is this the best practice?

Comment: Well keep this in mind. If a function only does one specific task, which conceivably only one link would execute, then put it directly in `ng-click` and be done with it. However, my answer is more about the potential of a function that might be shared by multiple options and you want a DRY approach of filtering it. If you have lots of options, like I said in my answer re: complex conditions, just do the filtering inside the function.